# Not able to change background of filter options in mui-datagrid

Tags: material-ui, outlook-addin, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm trying to change Colors of filter menu in Mui data grid, I'm able to change color of most of the components but background color of filter options is not changing.[Overlay for Filter menu options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRiRR.png)

I'm making Add-in for Outlook (MS Office 365 desktop version)

Package versions:
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.12",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.147",
"@mui/material": "^5.14.12",
"@mui/styled-engine": "^5.14.12",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.16.0",

I tried every styling given in documentation

`sx= {{ "& .MuiNativeSelect-select": {  backgroundColor:'#000, '& option':{ backgroundColor:'#000, background: '#000, color: COLORS.BG_GREY_DARK }, }, }}`
[Changed UI filter overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbqAA.png)
But overlay background color is not changing at all.